# How to create test cases based off of truth table values?

Tags: python, io, logic, python-itertools, spacy

I am creating output from tokens from spaCy from documentation. Using a truth table, I need to output all possible scenarios to test. The number of inputs can vary from input to input. If possible, I'd like it to be flexible to do 3+ inputs in this manner: ((a and b) or c).

Each scenario has a positive(True) or negative(False) aspect to its input (i.e. when the Input is set OR when the Input is not set) because all possible cases must be checked. 
For a 2 input scenario the following result is the goal:

Input: When "Input 1 is set" or when "Input 2 is not available" then "Fault is Detected".

Output:

1. Case 1:

   - Input 1 is set
   - Input 2 is not available
   - Fault is Detected
2. Case 2:

   - Input 1 is not set
   - Input 2 is not available
   - Fault is Detected
3. Case 3:

   - Input 1 is set
   - Input 2 is available
   - Fault is Detected
4. Case 4:

   - Input 1 is not set
   - Input 2 is available
   - Fault is not Detected

For 3 or more inputs, it will be exponentially increased.

I have no problem formatting/extracting the string values from the array or list into the correct format for my output. My major issue is the iteration through n inputs and mixed types of logic.

```
def truth_table(n):
    table = list(itertools.product([False, True], repeat=n))
    print(table)
truth_table(3)
```

This does not work for me as it only addresses the Inputs and not the resultant Output.

I've considered adding the inputs as tuples, assigning a value of 1 or 0 as an indicator of if its positive or the negative "version", and defining my truth table as a 2D list. Then iterating through each position of the Truth Table, and creating a new 2D array with the specified Input statements replacing the 0 and 1 values.

```
or_2 = [[0,0,0],
        [0,1,1],
        [1,0,1],
        [1,1,1]]

and_2 = [[0,0,0],
        [0,1,0],
        [1,0,0],
        [1,1,1]]
```

Comment: You need to characterize your output set for each test factor.  Then use `itertools.product` on those sets to generate all combinations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see where you are going with it but I am unclear at how I would characterize my output sets. It does not seem to be inclusive of the result, so I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value set (not "output" set) for each factor is the enumeration of possible values.  It appears that your input in quite canonical in this regard, as the set consists of a status word with/out the word "not" before it.  Thus, you have sets

```
A     {"not set", "set"}
B     {"not available", "available"}
out   {"not Detected", "Detected"}
```

You differentiate in and out by the separator "then".  You have 4 use cases because `AxB` has 4 elements.

You can reference these sets as list, or dict, if that fits your usage.  I'm not sure what you mean by "x type of logic"; if you're parsing a logical expression, then you need to look up exactly that type of parser.

In the given case, you need to extract the information for each clause and embody that into a positive generation for your third column, "out".  Note below that I assume your "then" keyword is logically "iff".

```
state_1 = "set"
state_2 = "not available"
op_1 = operator.__or__

table = []
for in1, in2 in itertools.product(A, B):
    val1 = in1 == state_1
    val2 = in2 == state_2
    table.append([val1, val2, op_1(val1, val2)])
```

Output (value of `table):

```
[[False, True, True],
 [False, False, False],
 [True, True, True],
 [True, False, True]]
```

With more inputs and more logical operations, you will need to turn to parsing mechanisms and build a tree of these binary operations.

Does this get you moving?

Comment: Yes this has gotten my wheels turning, thank you very much. When I attempt to recreate your code, I'm getting a ValueError on the for loop. "Not enough values to unpack, Expected 2, got 1". I am not understanding why.

Comment: That's because I slipped an extra container (brackets) into the code.  See the new code; there were several other errors.

Comment: I was able to figure this example out based on your edit. Thank you very much. This makes a lot of sense. I am not too familiar with building trees in Python, so I will have to study on the subject. But this has been a fantastic help! Thanks again.